# Find the image of the rectangle $1+i, 4+i,1+3i, 4+3i$, by $w=z^{2}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

The exercise states:

> Find the image of the rectangle $1+i, 4+i,1+3i, 4+3i$, by means of
> $w=z^{2}.$ Verify that the intersection angles are preserved and that
> a small rectangle is approximately preserved in shape under the
> transformation.  Analyze the case of a rectangle with vertices $0, 6,
> > 6+2i, 2i$. Can you generalize these results?

First, what I did was to find the component functions $u=x^{2}-y^{2}$ and $v=2xy$, then to be able to solve it I took the 4 segments, such as

$\left (E_{0}: x=1, 1\leq y \leq 3  \right ), \left (L_{1}: y=3, 1\leq x \leq 3  \right ) ,\left (E_{2}: x=4, 1\leq y \leq 3  \right )$ and $\left (L_{4}: y=1, 1\leq x \leq 3  \right )$

$\left (w(E_{0}): v^{2}+4u-1=0  \right ), \left (w(E_{1}): v^{2}-36u-324=0  \right ), \left (w(E_{2}): v^{2}+64u-1024=0  \right )$ and $\left (w(E_{3}): v^{2}-4u+1=0  \right )$

but when I plot them on a $UV$ plane, I can't find any sense, I hope you can help me a little bit, honestly I'm not understanding anything, thanks!

Comment: You should expect that a (straight) line will become a parabola under the squaring function — there will be exceptions. Perhaps you might verify this for a general horizontal line and a general vertical line.

Comment: You can first check what is the interval for the variable $Re(w)=u$, for $E_{0}$, if you consider $Re(z)=y$ then $2\leq 2y \leq 6$, this gives you an idea of how to plot the segments.